# tr1: boost vs vs2010, using shared_ptr without namespace

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost, namespaces, shared-ptr, tr1

trying to compile old project that has many uses of shared_ptr with the vs2010.
so, i have precompiled header (stdafx.h) with:

> ..
>   using namespace std;
>   ..
>
> #include "boost/shared_ptr"
>   using namespace boost;

and later in the code i intensively use shared_ptr spObject;

What should I change in the stdafx.h so that I will no need to replace everywhere in the code *shared_ptr* to *some_namespace::shared_ptr*?
Is it possible to do without namespace conflicts of boost/boost::tr1/std::tr1/std?

Now I have a lot of errors:

> error C2872: 'shared_ptr' : ambiguous symbol
>            could be 'k:\boost10\boost\smart_ptr\shared_ptr.hpp(165) : boost::shared_ptr'
>            or       'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\memory(1418) : std::tr1::shared_ptr'

Comment: May be it is not possible?  The only variant I see is to define the macro **#define shared_ptr std::shared_ptr**

Comment: Now I think it is not possible in c++ (without explicitly qualifying the namespace), it's so sad :(

Comment: This is one of the reasons that `using namespace` is bad. Don't use it in future projects. Or at the very least only use it on _one_ library. You can still avoid a lot of namespace qualifications by using more limited `using std::shared_ptr` etc. statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put `using namespace` in headers, as you've discovered it can break headers that follow, and because you can't change those headers there isn't much you can do about it.

At function scope you can use a using declaration to disambiguate:

```
void f()
{
  using std::tr1::shared_ptr;
  shared_ptr<int> p;
}
```

But that won't work in the global namespace, because you've already polluted that scope with the careless using directives.